# Multiple footnotes/citation for the same word in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice v7.1.

I have a sentence that have to end with citation/footnote. For example, the following sentence has a word and footnote "1".  In some cases I have a sentence that have more than one citation "1-4". However, when I do Insert/Footnote couple times to each other, then I get "1234".

How do I make it looks like "1-4" in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the numbers is a hyperlink to its corresponding footnote. I don't believe conversion to a hyphenated notation is possible because such notation would impede the provision of per-footnote hyperlinks.

To avoid "1234" being read as a single footnote, consider selecting all but the last of the footnote numbers and setting the character spacing to, e.g. 1.0pt. Selecting all of the numbers would add unnecessary space after the last.